# Why doesn't SF like the date value in my test class and won't let it deploy?

Tags: apex, unit-test

The following test class has 100% coverage but due to the date fields, it won't let it deploy to production. The date fields in production are regular date fields. What needs to be done?

Here is the error --> Invalid date: 2016/11/11

Here is the test class.

Thanks

```
@isTest 
public class test_chooseSeminar {

    @testSetup static void setupTestData(){

        List <Seminar__c> sem = new List<Seminar__c>();

        Seminar__c s1 = new Seminar__c();
        s1.Name = 'sem1';
        s1.Active__c = false;
        s1.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 1';
        s1.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s1.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s1.of_Participants__c = 3;

        Seminar__c s2 = new Seminar__c();
        s2.Name = 'sem2';
        s2.Active__c = false;
        s2.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 2';
        s2.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s2.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s2.of_Participants__c = 3;


        Seminar__c s3 = new Seminar__c();
        s3.Name = 'sem3';
        s3.Active__c = false;
        s3.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 3';
        s3.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s3.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s3.of_Participants__c = 3;


        Seminar__c s4 = new Seminar__c();
        s4.Name = 'sem4';
        s4.Active__c = false;
        s4.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 4';
        s4.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s4.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s4.of_Participants__c = 3;


        Seminar__c s5 = new Seminar__c();
        s5.Name = 'sem5';
        s5.Active__c = false;
        s5.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 5';
        s5.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s5.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s5.of_Participants__c = 3;

        Seminar__c s6 = new Seminar__c();
        s6.Name = 'sem6';
        s6.Active__c = false;
        s6.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 6';
        s6.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s6.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s6.of_Participants__c = 3;

        Seminar__c s7 = new Seminar__c();
        s7.Name = 'sem7';
        s7.Active__c = false;
        s7.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 7';
        s7.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s7.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s7.of_Participants__c = 3;

        Seminar__c s8 = new Seminar__c();
        s8.Name = 'sem8';
        s8.Active__c = false;
        s8.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 8';
        s8.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s8.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s8.of_Participants__c = 3;

        Seminar__c s9 = new Seminar__c();
        s9.Name = 'sem9';
        s9.Active__c = false;
        s9.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 9';
        s9.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s9.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s9.of_Participants__c = 3;

        Seminar__c s10 = new Seminar__c();
        s10.Name = 'sem10';
        s10.Active__c = false;
        s10.Seminar_Description__c = 'desc 10'; 
        s10.Start_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/11/11');
        s10.End_date__c = date.valueOf('2016/12/12');
        s10.of_Participants__c = 3;

        sem.add(s1);
        sem.add(s2);
        sem.add(s3);
        sem.add(s4);
        sem.add(s5);
        sem.add(s6);
        sem.add(s7);
        sem.add(s8);
        sem.add(s9);
        sem.add(s10);


        insert sem;

        // 
        Program__c program = new Program__c();
        program.Name = 'Test Program';
        program.Intendent_Number_of_Participants__c = 6;
        program.Seminar_1__c = sem[0].id;
        program.Seminar_2__c = sem[1].id;
        program.Seminar_3__c = sem[2].id;
        program.Seminar_4__c = sem[3].id;
        program.Seminar_5__c = sem[4].id;
        program.Seminar_6__c = sem[5].id;
        program.Seminar_7__c = sem[6].id;
        program.Seminar_8__c = sem[7].id;
        program.Seminar_9__c = sem[8].id;
        program.Seminar_10__c = sem[9].id;

        insert program;

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.FirstName = 'Test Contact FN';
        contact.LastName = 'Test Contact LN';
        insert contact;

        Application__c oa = new Application__c();
        oa.Name = 'Onward App test';
        oa.Contact__c = contact.id;
        oa.Program__c = program.id;
        insert oa;







    }

    static testMethod void testGetAllAccounts(){

        Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.vf_chooseSeminar')); 
        vfCnt_chooseSeminar controller; 



        test.startTest();

            List<Program__c> programList = [select id from Program__c];
            if (programList.size() > 0)
            {
                System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('pId', programList[0].id);
            }

            List<Contact> contactList = [select id from Contact];
            List<Application__c > onwardApplicationList = [select id from Application__c];
            List<Seminar__c> seminarList = [select id from Seminar__c];

            String programID = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('pId');        
            System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('inum', '021444234');        
            System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('ContactID18', contactList[0].id);
            System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('AppID18', onwardApplicationList[0].id);     
            System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('oaId', onwardApplicationList[0].id);
            System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('cntFN', 'ContactFirsName');    

            controller = new vfCnt_chooseSeminar();


            for (Seminar__c sem :seminarList)
            {
                sem.active__c = true;
            }
            Update seminarList;

            controller = new vfCnt_chooseSeminar();

            string s1 = controller.getItems;
            string s2 = controller.progName;
            string s3 = controller.semName1;
            string s4 = controller.semName2;
            string s5 = controller.semName3;
            string urlString = controller.urlString ;

            controller.getItems();
            controller.cancelAction();
            controller.saveItem();

            controller.semName1 = 'sem1';
            controller.semName2 = 'sem2';
            controller.semName3 = 'sem3';
            controller.saveItem();
            controller = new vfCnt_chooseSeminar();




        test.stopTest();


    }
}
```

Comment: if i am not wrong then issue with current user locale... I suggest instead of using `date.valueOf('2016/11/11')` try `date.newinstance(2016,11,11)`

Comment: You are not wrong sfdcweb. It worked. Make this an answer and I will mark it as answered. Many thanks.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b - as an aside your test class is not actually testing anything. To ensure that your code functions appropriately you need to be asserting that proper results were obtained. As it stands your code could not produce expected results and your tests would still pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

issue with current user locale...

### Reason

because when we use `date.valueOf('2016/11/11')` this date format should match with current user's locale date format else you will get this error

format can be

```
2016/11/11
2016-11-11
2016:11:11
```

Something like that, that's why

> Invalid date:

error occurs

### Solution

I suggest instead of using `date.valueOf('2016/11/11')` try `date.newinstance(2016,11,11)`

This way when you create date using new instance date will be formatted to current user locale.

**For a side note pls add asserts in your test class to check all the functionality.**

Comment: I accept the idea but I'd need help doing it. If you'd give me samples of what I have to do and instruction how to continue that would be great. Keep in mind some kind soul helped me with the test class like you and others helped write the project.